# Is it possible to add a tooltip containing component in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I need display tooltip that contains table. Table already exist as CustomComponent.
One of the solutions is duplicate table in HTML and use `setDescription()` method. But this looks little ugly, on my opinion.

Comment: What other option do you think is possible? You have to do the duplication in some way

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean ugly? Look at examples at [Vaadin Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.features.html#components.features.description) - they are really nice.

I tried to put table into `Button` description.

```
Button b = new Button("Button");
b.setIcon(FontAwesome.LEGAL);
b.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_FRIENDLY);

b.setDescription(
        "<table>\n" +
        "  <tr>\n" +
        "    <th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Month</th>\n" +
        "    <th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Savings</th>\n" +
        "  </tr>\n" +
        "  <tr>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">January</td>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">$100</td>\n" +
        "  </tr>\n" +
        "  <tr>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">July</td>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">$342</td>\n" +
        "  </tr>\n" +
        "  <tr>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">November</td>\n" +
        "    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\">$0</td>\n" +
        "  </tr>\n" +
        "</table>\n"
        );
```

I use `Valo` theme. And result is:

[image]

It has some size issue because `<th>` and `<td>` have padding. But simple increase table size makes it look better:

```
<table style=\"width:20em\">
```

[image]

You can customize it in any way. For example I added border:

[image]

You can also customize whole tooltip using SCSS.